# LibGDX: Tint Images for a ImageButton usin a Skin

Tags: java, json, libgdx

Hello I whant to make a ImageButton and the disabled image should be tinted gray.
I use a Skin and a .json file to define it. Is there a better way to get a gray tinted image than duplicate all images and add them to the texturepacker?

Comment: I guess i missunderstood the question. You are looking for some kind of grayshader right? (not a overlay or such)

Comment: sorry dont know what a grayshader is my goal is that disabled icons are gray (my icons are white).. And I whanted to know whats the best way (fastest for processing). As Example: AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way (or even the only way) to accomplish this is by using [shaders](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Shaders). Notice that `shaders` is a whole subject on its own, but once mastered, or even acquainted with, can give your game many cool capabilities, like graying out images.

As to your question: The first things that are needed, are shaders that will affect your images (or, in our case, `ImageButton`) in a way that will tint them gray. Luckily, these shaders have been implemented by somebody else, as an answer to a [similar question](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=7567). So, if we extract the required shaders from the above, we have the following:

**grey.vsh:**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
 
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
       vColor = a_color;
       vTexCoord = a_texCoord0;
       gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

**grey.fsh:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif
varying LOWP vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float grayscale;
void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);

    float gray = dot(texColor.rgb, vec3(0.96, 0.96, 0.96));
    texColor.rgb = mix(vec3(gray), texColor.rgb, grayscale);

    gl_FragColor = texColor * vColor;
}
```

Assuming these files are in your `assets` folder, we can create a [ShaderProgram](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.html) that will compile and use these shaders:

```
ShaderProgram shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("grey.vsh"), Gdx.files.internal("grey.fsh"));
```

Now we can extend `ImageButton` so that it'll use `shader` when we want it to be grey out. In this example, `ImageButton` is greyed out (or colored in) when it's clicked:

```
public class GreyedOutImageBtn extends ImageButton {
    private boolean isGreyedOut; // A flag that determines whther or not this should be greyed out
    public GreyedOutImageBtn(ImageButtonStyle style) {
        super(style);
        addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                // When clicked, toggle the grey effect
                Gdx.app.log("ClickListener", "Click");
                setIsGreyedOut(!getIsGreyedOut());
            }
        });
        isGreyedOut = false;
    }

    public boolean getIsGreyedOut() {
        return isGreyedOut;
    }

    public void setIsGreyedOut(boolean isGreyedOut) {
        this.isGreyedOut = isGreyedOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if (getIsGreyedOut()) {
            batch.end();
            batch.setShader(shader); // Set our grey-out shader to the batch
            batch.begin();
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha); // Draw the image with the greyed out affect
            batch.setShader(null); // Remove shader from batch so that other images using the same batch won't be affected
        }
        else {
            // If not required to be grey-out, do normal drawing
            super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        }
    }
}
```

This give the following results. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

After you've better understood `shaders`, you can build your own to be specific for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the tint color on disabled buttons, by using an [ImageButtonStyle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.html) object, and use the [newDrawable(Drawable drawable, Color tint)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.html#newDrawable-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color-) method from the [Skin](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Skin.html) class.

In code it could look a little something like this. Notice that we have initialised the Skin object with a Texture Atlas, which holds our UI Textures. See [the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin#resources) for more information.

```
// Create the tint color. Notice we use LibGDX Color class
Color tintColor = new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);

ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle btnStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
btnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("my_button");
btnStyle.disabled = skin.newDrawable("my_button", tintColor);

ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(btnStyle);
```